# Foreach equivalent on variadic function

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-functions

Did some searching and couldn't find an answer to this question so apologies if a repost. I want to call the same function with the same arg on a bunch of different objects. I currently implemented it like this:

```
void callWithArg(const char* msg) { }

template <typename HEAD, typename.... TAIL>
void callWithArg(HEAD&& head, TAIL&&... tail, const char* msg) {
    head.foo(msg);
    callWithArg(tail..., msg);
}
```

Obviously that in itself is not a particularly tedious bit of code, I was just wondering if there was a simpler or cleaner way of iterating over that parameter pack than this kind of recursive invocation? Thanks!

Comment: Hopefully [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261183/how-to-make-generic-computations-over-heterogeneous-argument-packs-of-a-variadic) can help

Comment: It depends a lot whether you care about the order in which the iteration is done or not.

Comment: The solution proposed by @MarcGlisse in the linked Q&A is simple and effective. If you want a more powerful and generalized processing, then  you can take my framework as an inspiration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the most concise way I know to express this:

```
template<typename ...T>
void callWithArg(const char *msg, T &&...t) {
  int dummy[] = { 0, (t.foo(msg), 0)... };
}
```

The pack expansion expands to a list of expressions of type `int`, which are used to initialize the array `dummy` (which we throw away). The calls to `foo` are sequenced, because in C++11, elements of a list-initialization are sequenced left-to-right.

If you add a `#include <initializer_list>`, you can slightly simplify this to:

```
auto dummy = { 0, (t.foo(msg), 0)... };
```

You may also want to suppress the "unused variable" warning which various compilers produce on this code, with

```
(void) dummy;
```

The initial `0,` is included to avoid an error if the function is given no arguments other than `msg`. I also reordered your function's parameters to put the pack last, so that the types in the pack can be deduced.