# Iterating variadic template types

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, initializer-list, multiple-arguments

I've been stuck on this for a while and I ran out of ideas, help appreciated!

The following segments are example code, to simplify.

Assume the following:

```
class Base; 
class DerivedA : public Base; 
class DerivedB : public Base;
```

and  this:

```
class Manager {
public:
    std::map<std::type_index, Base*> container;

    template<typename ...T>
    void remove() {
        // Iterate through templates somehow and...
        container.erase(typeid(T));
    }
}
```

Basically I'm storing, in a container, unique instances of derived classes, by using the std::type_index as a key. Allowing me to do something like:

```
manager.remove<DerivedA>();
```

With that said, I'd like to be able to do the same thing, but allow multiple templates directly to remove multiple instances at once, as such:

```
manager.remove<DerivedA, DerivedB>()
```

I know it is possible to iterate through variadic templates as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15502003/4565712), but I keep getting compilation errors...

> error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer-list' to 'std::initializer_list'
>
> error C3535: cannot deduce type for 'auto' from 'initializer-list'

...when I try to run this code:

```
template<typename ...T>
void remove() {
    // Iterate through templates somehow and...
    auto list = {(container.erase(typeid(T)))... };
}
```

Any ideas?
Thank you very much.

Comment: `int dummy[] = { (c.erase(typeid(T)), 0)... };`

Comment: Woah, your solution worked perfectly right out of the box... I've tried something similar earlier but without the 0. What's the difference?

Comment: Your code should be fine as-is, might be an MSVC bug (`erase` returns a `size_t` so that should be fine). It should just deduce `list` to be `std::initialize_list<size_t>`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you just ran into an MSVC bug. The compile error:

> error C3535: cannot deduce type for 'auto' from 'initializer-list'

isn't valid. C++11 does allow deduction for `auto` from a *braced-init-list*, as long as all the types are the same. In your case, `std::map::erase` returns a `size_t`, so it should compile. [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aeb31a70a025e0c4) is an example with basically your code.

To get around that, you may just be able to explicitly provide the type:

```
size_t dummy[] = {m.erase(typeid(T))...};
```

Or, just in case somebody passes in no types, prepend a zero:

```
size_t dummy[] = {0u, m.erase(typeid(T))...};
```

That way, the array will always have at least one element. The more typical usage, which [Kerrek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31368699/iterating-variadic-template-types#comment50716831_31368699) suggested in his comment, would be the following:

```
int dummy[] = {0, (void(m.erase(typeid(T)), 0)... };
```

That will work regardless of the expression that you will replace `m.erase(...)` with, since the value of `(..., 0)` is `0`. The `void` is there to avoid issues with overloading `operator,`.

Comment: Ah yes, I see, makes sense. I was wondering why it wouldn't compile because it was exactly as others' solutions. Thank you for clarifying.