# Call a common named method of all base classes from a derived class with multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, design-patterns, variadic-templates

I realize that what I am trying to do is possibly wrong, so I would gladly accept and alternative approach.
All code below is just an illustration.

Suppose I have a derived class, with multiple base classes:

```
template<typename... Bases> class Derived : public Bases...{
public:
    VariadicTemplate(BaseClasses&&... base_classes) : BaseClasses(base_classes)... {}

    void DoAllFoo();
};
```

And all the base classes have a method, named DoFoo(). I was going to derive them from a common base with a public method Foo():

```
class CommonBase {
public:
    virtual Foo() { DoFoo() };
protected:
    virtual void DoFoo() = 0;
};

class Base1 : public CommonBase {
    DoFoo() { /* displays something */ };
};

class Base2 : public CommonBase {
    DoFoo() { /* displays something else */ };
};

....
```

Now this is how I was going to use it. I want to instantiate some amount the Derived class objects, specified with different Base classes:

```
Devired<Base1, Base2> x;
Devired<Base5, Base7, Base21> y;
...
x.DoAllFoo();
y.DoAllFoo();
```

I want (somehow) the Derived's DoAllFoo() to "iterate" over it's Base classes and call each classes Foo() method.

The only solution I can imagine is to have some set of function pointers/functors/whatever in Derived and make all Bases register their Foo() method in this set when constructing. This will probably work, but look like it could be done better.

I hope, that I am not familiar with some common pattern to solve this problem (or I am just pure wrong), so please advise.
Thank you.

Comment: Like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd75b0dbaaf89b4b) ?

Comment: Yep. Thanks, I've also just found this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501322/iterating-over-variadic-templates-type-parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want either:

```
void DoAllFoo()
{
    using expand = int[];
    static_cast<void>(expand{ 0, (static_cast<Bases*>(this)->Foo(), void(), 0)... });
}
```

or:

```
void DoAllFoo()
{
    using expand = int[];
    static_cast<void>(expand{ 0, (Bases::Foo(), void(), 0)... });
}
```

depending on whether the call to `Foo` itself should be virtual or not.

Comment: Or soon even better `(Bases::Foo(), ...);`

Answer (score 1):

The pattern I would use is simply composition as opposed to inheritance. Why don't you just make objects of base classes as members of what you now call `Derived`? You can simply store them into a `std::vector` and then iterate over it inside `DoAllFoo`.

For example:

```
class FooWrapper {

// ...

public:
  void DoAllFoos();

private:
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<CommonBase> > bases_;   


} 

void FooWrapper::DoAllFoos() 
{
   for(auto& base: bases)
     base->DoFoo();
}
```

Comment: Well, I agree that that does makes scene, but I'm not sure if this solution's usage would be as flexible as the templated one.

Comment: I don't see any real need for templates here, unless I am missing something.

Comment: could you please provide an example usage for your solution?

Comment: The usage would be identical to the one you are suggesting, with object instantiation instead of template instantiation (depending on the constructor that you choose to implement). For example a natural choice in this case could be to implement a constructor that takes an initializer list of base classes and uses it to initialize the internal vector. Instead of `Derived<Base1, Base2> x;` you would have `FooWrapper x{Base1(), Base2()}`.

Comment: Just to further clarify. My answer was based on the fact that you asked for an alternative approach. In my opinion the variadic template approach is a bit of an overkill for the problem.

Comment: I see, thank you. I'm sorry for a misleading question, now I understand your suggestion perfectly.